# MaxWidth of 'Auto'?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to create a grid that deals with screens of different sizes. My code currently looks like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" ... />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" ... />
</Grid>
```

This doesn't work correctly because I end up with a huge empty space at the end of the first column when I'm in fullscreen, and I want the text in each column to be adjacent. However, it DOES correctly shrink the first column when I shrink/resize the screen.

I also tried using code like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" ... />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" ... />
</Grid>
```

This code looks perfect when the app is fullscreen, but when I shrink/resize the screen the first column will NOT shrink to fit. It leaves my grid the same size, which pushes my text off of the smaller screen.

How can I cap the width at whatever size 'Auto' would be, and still have it resize like it is '*'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I cap the width at whatever size 'Auto' would be, and still have it resize like it is '*'?

According to [Define page layouts with XAML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/layout/layouts-with-xaml), `Auto` means the column will size to fit its content, `*` means after the Auto columns are calculated, the column gets part of the remaining width.

`Width` of `ColumnDefinition` cannot be set to `Auto` as well as `*`. But as your issue is when set `Auto` to both `ColumnDefinition`, it pushes your text off of the smaller screen, so here we may use [`AdaptiveTrigger`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.adaptivetrigger.aspx). We can set `Width` to `*` by default this can ensure resize don't cut off the text. When the window resize to a larger size that will not lead the text cut off, the `AdaptiveTrigger` can help change the  `Width` property from `*` to `Auto`. For example:

```
<Grid
   Background="Azure"
   BorderBrush="Pink"
   BorderThickness="2">
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <ColumnDefinition x:Name="col1" Width="*" />
       <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <TextBlock        
       Grid.Column="0"        
       Foreground="Blue"
       Text="layouttest1layouttest1layouttest1layou"
       TextWrapping="Wrap"  />
   <TextBlock     
       Grid.Column="1"           
       Foreground="Red"
       Text="layouttest2layouttest2layouttest2layouttest2layout"
       TextWrapping="Wrap" />
   <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
       <VisualStateGroup>
           <VisualState>
               <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                   <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="600" />
               </VisualState.StateTriggers>
               <VisualState.Setters>
                   <Setter Target="col1.Width" Value="Auto" />
               </VisualState.Setters>
           </VisualState>
       </VisualStateGroup>
   </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
</Grid>
```

The value of `MinWindowWidth`  depend on the total `Width` of `TextBlock`. More details please reference the [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlResponsiveTechniques?amp;clcid=0x409).

Updated code as follows, if `Width` of `TextBlock` is dynamic.

XAML code

```
<Grid
    Background="Azure"
    BorderBrush="Pink"
    BorderThickness="2">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="col1" Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock        
        Grid.Column="0"  
        x:Name="txt1"
        Foreground="Blue"
        Text="layouttest1layouttest1layouttest1layou"
        TextWrapping="Wrap"  />
    <TextBlock     
        Grid.Column="1"           
        Foreground="Red"
        x:Name="txt2"
        Text="layouttest2layouttest2layouttest2layouttest2layout"
        TextWrapping="Wrap" />     
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState>
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger x:Name="adptivetrigger"   />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="col1.Width" Value="Auto" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
</Grid>
```

Code behind

```
 private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     var testwidth = txt1.ActualWidth + txt2.ActualWidth;
     adptivetrigger.MinWindowWidth = testwidth;          
 }
```

Comment: Closer, but where did you get the value MinWindowWidth="600"? Since the length of each TextBlock can vary I'll never know the exact flipping point between * and Auto. Don't I need '600' to be the width of the first column when it's set as Auto? And couldn't I just set that value to be the first column's MaxWidth and get the same results?

Comment: @TS, The `MinWindowWidth` is the summary `ActualWidth` of  the two `TextBlock` . If the actual width is dynamic, you can calculate it code behind and set it the the trigger. I updated the code in the reply you can reference. By the way, if my reply helped you, could you please mark as accepted.

Comment: I've got what I wanted... although I ended up dropping the VisualStateManager. Basically I took your code-behind and, instead of using it to set 'adptivetrigger.MinWindowWidth', used it to set 'col1.MaxWidth'. It still needs tweaking to make it work with the ItemsControl it's located inside (probably make MaxWidth a binding), but the concept is solid. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this one

```
<Grid>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<TextBlock Grid.Column="0" ... HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
<TextBlock Grid.Column="1" ... HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

Here, I just added HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" property that will align textblock stretch within the column

Comment: No good. If the first column has only a little text then there is still a gap between each TextBlock. If there is a lot of text then the first column will not expand to fit the text, even if there's a bunch of empty space at the end of the second column.

Comment: Do you want to adjust first column's width according to text that it contains? then what should be happen with the second column if second column has some text?

Comment: What I want is for both columns to act as if their width is auto BUT when the screen shrinks or their combined text is too big, only the first column will get shrunk or have cut-off text. The first column's TextBlock has TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" to make it fit the column if it's too small. This is because the first column contains a description of a project, which I can exclude part of, and the second column contains the current status of a project, which should not ever be hidden or cut off. I also need to eliminate any gap between those TextBlocks.